# CW Structure (dimensions $n$ to $n+4$) of $K(\mathbb{Z}/2, n)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

There exists a CW complex $K$ that is an Eilenberg-Maclane Space $K(\mathbb{Z}/2, n)$ with the following skeleton (for $n$ big enough, say $\ge 3$):

- One $e^0$.
- One $e^n$, whose boundary is collapsed to the basepoint. So $K^{(n)}=S^n$.
- One $e^{n+1}$, with $\partial e^{n+1}\to K^{(n)}$ of degree 2. This gives $\pi_n(K)=\mathbb{Z}/2$. Via homotopy long exact sequence, one gets $\pi_{n+1}(K^{(n+1)})=\mathbb{Z}/2$, via the Hopf map $S^{n+1}\to S^n \hookrightarrow K^{(n+1)}$, giving $f:S^{n+1}\to K^{(n+1)}$.
- One $e^{n+2}$ with $\partial e^{n+2}\overset{f}\to K^{(n+1)}$, to kill $\pi_{n+1}(K)=0$.

Unfortunately, when I tried to compute $\pi_{n+2}(K^{(n+2)})$, I needed $\pi_{n+2}(K^{(n+1)})$, which is either the Klein group or $\mathbb{Z}/4$. In general, it seems like proceeding to give an explicit CW structure for $K^{(n+3)}$ and $K^{(n+4)}$ would be very hard. Does anyone know if this CW structure has been studied? Thank you!

Comment: MathJax works in the title, don't you know?

Comment: The construction "add enough cells to kill higher homotopy, inductively" is standard, but I have not seen examples of this structure explicitly worked out like this, besides some $K(G,n)$'s with special cell structures like $K(\mathbb{Z}/2,1)$ or $K(\mathbb{Z},2)$.

Comment: This might be too fancy, but if you start with the chain complex that is $\mathbb Z/2$ in degree $n$ and $0$ elsewhere, apply the Dold Kan correspondence to get  a simplicial abelian group that is a $K(\mathbb Z/2, n)$, then you can take geometric realization to get a cell structure.

Comment: You might like to consult Wu's book "Homotopy Theory of the Suspensions of the Projective Plane" for some useful information, in particular that $\pi_{n+2}S^n\cup_2e^{n+1}\cong\mathbb{Z}_4$.

Comment: My calculations give me $\pi_{n+2}K^{(n+2)}\cong \mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z_2}$, although I wouldn't be surprised if I have made an error.